# PyQt Layout seems not to work - why all is overlayed?

Tags: python, layout, pyqt

I need help. I am adding in QT Designer two buttons then I use horizontal Layout. Ctrl + R - everything looks fine.

Then I convert the Form into Python:

```
pyuic4.bat Form2.ui > Form2.py
```

And run the app. Layout seems not to work. All the buttons are overlayed.

The py code for the Form (I didn't change anything):

```
class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Form"))
        Form.resize(383, 222)
        self.horizontalLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(Form)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("horizontalLayout"))
        self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton"))
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        self.pushButton_2 = QtGui.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton_2"))
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_2)

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form", None))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "PushButton 1", None))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("Form", "PushButton 2", None))
```

And the code for the app:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from Form2 import Ui_Form

class MyForm(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_Form()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = MyForm()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I would appreciate any help.
Bye, Wojtek

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qmainwindow.html):

> QMainWindow has its own layout... The layout has a center area that
>   can be occupied by any kind of widget.

[image: QMainWindow Layout]

```
**Creating a main window without a central widget is not supported.**
```

Some things to read into this:

1. You cannot change the layout of QMainWindow.
2. You need a central widget that will manage all other widgets.

So change your app to reflect that, by adding a central widget and running setupUi on that widget.

```
class MyForm(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        central_widget = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget) # new central widget
        self.ui = Ui_Form()
        self.ui.setupUi(central_widget)  # target central_widget for UI setup
```

Comment: Thank you for help. That's exactly what I missed: central widget. Now it works! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

OK, although the help above works I've find out why I didn't get expecting result of layouts just by means of Qt Designer. Simply the reason was I used Widget (Form) instead of a Main Window. In a Main Window layouts works ok.